# Post data from Server side in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, server-side

I am making a automation website to send multiple files to an another site to prevent filling form every time to send a file.

I want to to make the POST request from server, because AJAX doesn't allow request to other domains.

How I can make this?

I am using Spring MVC3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apache [http components](http://hc.apache.org/) - it allows you to perform http requests. You can also use (without 3rd party libraries) `new URL(..).openConnection()`, but it's less pleasant to code with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/) to implement pretty much any HTTP calls you want in your application. Also, note that it is possible to do cross domain AJAX with certain helper technologies like Flash ... if you really needed too.